# How to find solution of these equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}x_1+y_1=a\\ x_1-y_2=b\\ y_1-x_2=c\\ x_2+y_2=d \end{cases}$$

How to find a solution for these equations because from elimination and substitution method I end up with 2 equations with totally same variable part on L.H.S like below:

$$\begin{cases}y_1+y_1=A\\ y_1+y_2=B\end{cases}$$

Comment: So, it must be $A=B$ and there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Label the equations (1),(2),(3),(4). Then (1)-(2) gives $y_1+y_2=a-b$ and (3)+(4) gives $y_1+y_2=c+d$. If $a-b\ne c+d$, then the equations are inconsistent and have no solutions. If $a-b=c+d$, then one equation is redundant and you have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Writing the augmented matrix of this linear system in reduced row echelon form, you obtain that either there are no solutions, or the solutions make an affine line in $K^4$. I ordered the unknowns as $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$:

\begin{align}
&\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&0&a \\
1&0&0&-1&b\\
0&-1& 1&0&c \\
0&1&0&1&d
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&0&a \\
0&1&0&1&d \\
1&0&0&-1&b\\
0&-1& 1&0&c \\
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&0&a \\
0&1&0&1&d \\
0&0&-1&-1&b-a\\
0&-1& 1&0&c \\
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow \\
\rightsquigarrow&\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&1&0&a \\
0&1&0&1&d \\
0&0&-1&-1&b-a\\
0&0& 1&1&c+d \\
\end{array}\right]\rightsquigarrow
\left[\begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&0&0&-1&b \\
0&1&0&1&d \\
0&0&1&1&a-b\\
0&0& 0&0&-a+b+c+d \\
\end{array}\right].
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Pretty much the standard way to solve any linear system (in fact, the canonical)

Comment: your answer is nice and helping and i found another same question as mine because it is required for solving a problem so many people asking https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104871/how-to-get-only-positive-solution-of-a-system-of-4-variables-and-equations?rq=1

Comment: if anybody can give more clarification from link in above comment that would be thankfull.